# apt-mirror many repositories?

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

We're setting up an `apt-mirror` box to provide package access to machines that generally have no WAN. In `mirror.list`, I added the base ubuntu repositories as well as all the external deb repos we use (ceph, cumulus, docker, nginx, postgres, nodesource, etc), and it appears to download them as expected.

But when it comes to configuring a client to use the mirror, I'm receiving the package list for the base ubuntu items, but not seeing anything from the external repos.

Is this scenario a gross misuse of apt-mirror ?
Should I set up one mirror per external source (docker-mirror, ceph-mirror)?

I suspect the client `sources.list` needs more than what it has, but I'm not certain what to add. Below is the client sources.list, `{{custom_mirror}}` is a placeholder for our real mirror domain.

```
# client /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty main

deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main

deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://{{custom_mirror}}/ubuntu trusty-security universe
```

Answer (score 2):

Self answer;  sorry about the poor form.
My problem was a combination of *not serving* all of the collected repos, and general organization.

In the end, the client sources.list (and matching mirror layout) looks more like:

```
deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/archive.ubuntu.com trusty main universe
deb http://{{custom_mirror}}/apt.dockerproject.org ubuntu-trusty main
```

I gave each mirrored repo a subdirectory off the http root using it's original name. Hope this helps someone else!